# suitable framework and technology stack for my project?

Tags: java, android, node.js, jsp

I have to submit a project in my college for which I have only two months! I already have an idea of what to make but don't know which technology to go for. I want to use something latest so as to make my project more efficient and flexible.

I wanted to make something like "Attendance Management System" in which we can take attendance of students and save the records on underlying database, also to perform some kind of data mining on the data (to find some interesting patterns like the_most_attended_lecture or to apply some probabilistic model to estimate the_next_possible_bunk or analysis based on an individual student record to compute anything interesting...) and then to develop an android app for the UI that can handle request and response to the database.

I'm really confused as what to go for? Currently I have no knowledge of the following but my friend suggested me to choose among them: node.js (with express framework) REST API, PHP, JSP, JSON, and MongoDB.

I would really appreciate your help guys. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Choosing technology is depand upon the project. Analize the project and check which technology is suitable and supportable. If you have to develop the project with in short span of Time with out considering technology suitability, choose nodejs and for db -  mongodb.

Comment: I understand that your project is due. But these sort of questions are very broad to answer. So be specific and ask several questions I'd you have to

Comment: Questions about what libraries or what technologies to use are generally too broad and primarily opinion based, and tend to be off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: This question here looks virtually identical to [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32415213/suitable-framework-and-stack-for-my-project) from 10 hrs ago that was put on hold as primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets try to decide the technology stack according to your requirements.

**1. Latest technology -** Although you didn't give any justification for this requirement. But as you want, latest fads going on are for web server are **node, go lang, nginx**(if you happen to choose php in the end) and **mongo, elastic search** for data store.

**2. Less amount of time -** You have only 2 months to learn the technology, build the prototype , design the db schema, implement everything and test. Hence I will suggest you to go with **node.js or php**(I am assuming you are familiar with JS and php).

**3. High database IO -** I don't know what scale you will be working upon but the only major thing you server will be doing is DB IO, hence you should choose some **non-blocking technology** and among them most famous is **NODE.JS**.

Node.js is something which is fulfilling every requirement.
If I were you, I would have choose **express.js** (express init and you are ready to go), **Mysql** (If you are not familiar with any NoSql as mysql seems to be fulfilling every requirement). And android app could be anything like **cordova** as app is doing nothing but HTTP request and some presentation of data.